# Puppet using /var/lib/puppet/.puppet/ as default config dir

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm running a CentOS 6 box with puppet 3.0.2.
The `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` on the puppet server does not seem to do anything, so I ran:

> puppet master --no-daemonize --logdest console --verbose --debug

And I get the following:

> Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'reportdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/.puppet/var/reports]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/.puppet/var/reports"}'
>
> Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'manifestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/.puppet/manifests]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/.puppet/manifests"}'

etc.

It doesn't seem to be using /etc/puppet at all.
Is this normal?
How do I make it look under /etc/puppet?

Comment: What's your `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` look like?

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behaviour now according to [Bug #16637](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16637). When running on the command line (as a non-root user) you will need to pass the --confdir parameter to override the default location of ~/.puppet/puppet.conf e.g.:

```
puppet master --confdir /etc/puppet --no-daemonize --logdest console --verbose --debug
```

If you have updated to Puppet 3 and had previously configured the Puppet Master to run within Passenger as a non-root user you will also need to update your [config.ru](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/ext/rack/files/config.ru) file to supply these parameters e.g.:

```
# Rack applications typically don't start as root.  Set --confdir and --vardir
# to prevent reading configuration from ~puppet/.puppet/puppet.conf and writing
# to ~puppet/.puppet
ARGV << "--confdir" << "/etc/puppet"
ARGV << "--vardir"  << "/var/lib/puppet"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running puppet with the `--confdir` option.  For example:

```
puppet master --confdir /etc/puppet
```